# SQLite vs. Text file in IOS development XCode4.2

Tags: ios, web-services, sqlite, text, xcode4

Currently, I cannot decide what should i use text file or SQLite for my IOS application (target to ipad). i have 5000 records to retrieve from web service and save into some repository. my first idea is to save all records inside into text file but it will slow and so many processes for specific record searching. searching from text file is so troublesome than searching from database. but i am totally newbie in SQLite. my concern is if i use SQLite, will it be  effect the user? do user need to download any file to run application?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQLite (or, much better, [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)) will have no affect on the user. No additional downloads or anything like that. You build it into the app, seamless to the end-user. So do whatever is best for your solution.

While you should use Core Data, if you use SQLite, you should consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which gets you out of the weeds of SQLite programming